# Batch convert json to csv python

Tags: python, json, batch-file, csv

Similar to this question [batch process text to csv using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817082/batch-process-text-to-csv-using-python)

I've got a batch of json files that need to be converted to csv so that they can be imported into Tableau.

The first step was to get json2csv ( https://github.com/evidens/json2csv ) working, which I did. I can successfully convert a single file via the command line.

Now I need an operation that goes through the files in a directory and converts each in a single batch operation using that json2csv script.

TIA

Comment: Can you post your code? We could then point at what you're doing wrong, which is always more educational.

Comment: something like `for file in os.listdir(".")` ?

Answer (score 1):

I actually created a jsontocsv python script to run myself. It basically reads the json file in chunks, and then goes through determining the rows and columns of the csv file.

Check out [Opening A large JSON file in Python with no newlines for csv conversion Python 2.6.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731270/opening-a-large-json-file-in-python-with-no-newlines-for-csv-conversion-python-2) for the details of what was done and how it built the .csv from the json. The actual conversion would depend on your actual json format.

The [json parse function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708192/how-do-i-use-the-json-module-to-read-in-one-json-object-at-a-time/21709058#21709058) with a chunk size of 0x800000 was what was used to read in the json data.

If the data becomes available at specific times, you can set this up using crontab.

I used

```
 from optparse import OptionParser
```

to get the input and output files as arguments as well as setting the various options that were required for the analysis and mapping.

You can also use a batch script in the given directory

```
for f in *.json; do
  mybase=`basename $f .json`
  json2csv $f -o ${mybase}.csv
done
```

alternatively, use find with the -exec {} option

If you want all the json files to go into a single .csv file you can use

```
json2csv *.json -o myfile.csv
```

Comment: Please, always quote filenames in shell scripts. *ALWAYS*. This will break as soon as you get a filename with a space, bracket, dollar sign, etc.